# L2 norm of a function w.r.t. its gradient

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, normed-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I was wondering whether it is possible to generalise the statement of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218695/l2-norm-of-a-function-and-its-derivative), i.e. I would like to show something like
$$\|f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C \|\nabla f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)},$$
where $\Omega=[0,1]^n$ and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a suitable function with $f=0$ on the vertices of $\Omega$ (and $C$ does not depend of $f$). Although this seems to be a standard question I was not able to find anything on this for $n\geq2$.

My approach was the following (given that everything is well-defined). By $f(0)=0$ we know that:
$$f(x)=\int^1_0\langle\nabla f(hx),x\rangle dh=\int^{|x|}_0\langle\nabla f(uw),w\rangle du,$$
where $w=x/|x|$. If I am not mistaken, using polar coordinates (cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954558/polar-coordinates-in-mathbb-rn?rq=1)) should give the identity
$$\|f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}=\int^{\rho_n}_0\int_{A_n}f(rw)^2dwr^{n-1}dr$$
with $A_n=S^{n-1}\cap[0,1]^n$, $S^{n-1}$ sphere and $\rho_n=\sqrt{n}$ being the "diagonal" (or diameter) of $\Omega$. Next I would like to combine the two preceding equalities to obtain the desired inequality. This should give (if I did not mix anything up with the gradient) the equation
$$\|f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}=\int^{\rho_n}_0\int_{A_n}\Big(\int^r_0\langle\nabla f(uw),w\rangle du\Big)^2dwr^{n-1}dr.$$
Cauchy-Schwarz now yields
$$\|f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq\int^{\rho_n}_0\int_{A_n}\int^r_0|\nabla f(uw)|^2dudwr^ndr$$
but I do not see how I could end up with $\|\nabla f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$ since I would need the term $u^{n-1}$ to pop-up somewhere.

Any ideas are appreciated especially for the special case $n=2$. In particular, I would like to consider Sobolev functions with $s\in(1,2)$ to obtain
$$\|f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C \|\nabla f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C' \sum_{|\alpha|=1}\| f^{(\alpha)}\|^2_{H^{s-1}(\Omega)},$$
such that $C'$ does not depend on $f$ and I think that I already showed that the second inequality holds.

Comment: This is the [Poincaré-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality).

Comment: Poincaré's inequality requires that $f$ vanishes on the entire boundary of $\Omega$. In the question, it is only required that $f = 0$ on the vertices of $\Omega$. However, the condition "$f = 0$ on the vertices of $\Omega$" does not make sense for $f \in H^1(\Omega)$ in dimensions $n \ge 2$.

Comment: Still, one might use Poincaré in this way: Extend $f$ to the unit ball $B^n$, say to $\tilde f$, such that $\tilde f=0$ on the boundary of $B^n$ and $|\nabla\tilde f|_{H^{s-1}(B^n)}\leq C'\sum_{|\alpha|=1}\|f^{(\alpha)}\|^2_{H^{s-1}(\Omega)}$. Then one might use $\|f\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq\|\tilde f\|^2_{L^2(B^n)}\leq C\|\nabla\tilde f\|^2_{L^2(B^n)}$ and try to bound the latter one by $|\nabla\tilde f|_{H^{s-1}(B^n)}$.

Comment: @gerw: That is why I wrote "if everything is well-defined". If $s>n/2$ then the condition should make sense and we could also apply Poincaré, right? Since you replied to the last questions I posed: I would like to show the [posted inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2712985/simple-l2-bound-for-bivariate-sobolev-function-on-a-square) for $C$ independent of $f$ and I know that this is true for $f\in H^s(\mathbb{R}^n),\ s\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry for the spam: I mean extend $f$ to the ball of radius $\rho_n$ and I know that my desired inequality (from my older linked post) holds true if the underlying set is the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$ (independent of $C$).

Comment: Yes, you can work with $s > n/2$, but the initial inequality in your post corresponds to the case $s = 1$ and $s \le n / 2$ as soon as $n \ge 2$.

Comment: It should be possible to construct an explicit counterexample: Define $f_\epsilon(x) = \log|\log(\epsilon+|x)| - \log|\log \epsilon|$.Then reflect $f_\epsilon$ such that $f_\epsilon$ is defined and continuous on $[0,1]^2$. This $f_\epsilon$ belongs to $H^1$ and is zero at the corners.  Then $\|\nabla f_\epsilon\|_{L^2}$ should be uniformly bounded, while $\|f_\epsilon\|_{L^2}$ blows up for $\epsilon\to0$,

Comment: @daw Do you mean by reflecting that your definition of $f_{\varepsilon}$ is given on $[0,1/2]^2$ and then you reflect it on $\{x_1=1/2\}$ to obtain its extension on $[1/2,1]\times[0,1/2]$ etc.?

Comment: @User123 yes ..